# How to run a docker meant for Linux, on Mac

Tags: docker

So we downloaded this docker image that we need to run on the machines of me and a friend. I am on a mac and he is on a linux box. We are not techie people so please forgive this naive question :)

When running the docker using `docker build -t app-name/site.com .` we were running into some very cryptic G++ errors which sent us on a wild goose chase and a vicious circle of googling and debugging. In the end we figured out that my friend's machine was Linux 18.04, but in the `Dockerfile` it said `FROM ubuntu:16.04`. So when we updated this to `FROM ubuntu:18.04` his docker build was successful and he was able to launch the app.

So now we are trying to figure out how to get this running in my mac. Does anyone know what update we should do to this line to get it running in mac? I am running macOS Catalina.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The docker build command builds the docker image. Since the docker image is already available you should use the docker run command to run it. The run command should work on both the systems without any changes

Comment: Docker Desktop for Mac runs a hidden Linux VM, and should be able to natively run Linux containers without special setup (there are no MacOS containers).

Answer (score 0):

Docker is originally developed for Linux community. Then it is ok for Mac.

Here is one example of how to make your mac get a Linux container. Run this

```
docker pull ubuntu
```

This means you are able to construct a Ubuntu env on your mac machine.

FYI, you can release your docker image on docker's website then fetch it on your mac.

Refer to: https://ropenscilabs.github.io/r-docker-tutorial/04-Dockerhub.html